# Next step up from QuickTime screen recordings?

Tags: video, video-editing, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro and I have started doing `QuickTime` recordings of my code development and how to use some of the web interfaces I design.  It's a quick and easy process, and then I load it to YouTube.

I'm quite happy with this for now, but if I could have my wish of three additional features to add, the would be in this order:

- 1, 2, and 3 (just kidding but definitely #1) -  ability to insert static frames/images that may be something like "Step 1: Logging In".  This cue could make the video more organized
- 2. Ability to fade out/in - this would be a nice-to-have
- 3. Ability to overlay an image on the recording for a period of time.

My first thought is, is there any way to do at least #1 using QuickTime alone?  And then of course, is there any software out there that is simple to learn that will do these things?  Thanks